# How are repository details specified in apt?

Tags: repository, localrepository

I ran `apt list --installed` command and got this output:

```
xterm/xenial,now 322-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
xul-ext-ubufox/xenial,now 3.2-0ubuntu1 all [installed]
xz-utils/xenial,now 5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
yelp/xenial,now 3.18.1-1ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
yelp-xsl/xenial,now 3.18.1-1 all [installed]
zeitgeist-core/xenial,now 0.9.16-0ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
zeitgeist-datahub/xenial,now 0.9.16-0ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
zenity/xenial,now 3.18.1.1-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
zenity-common/xenial,now 3.18.1.1-1ubuntu2 all [installed]
zip/xenial,now 3.0-11 amd64 [installed]
zlib1g/unknown,xenial-updates,now 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 amd64 [installed]
```

Why `unknown` instead of `xenial` when updated from local repository?

What is this `now` repository?

Comment: Please add textual output instead of an image

Comment: Also describe how did you generate the required index files for your local repository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `unknown`

The `unknown` part comes from the entry for `Suite` key in `Release` file for a debian repository. I think you've generated a local repository without properly setting the required keys for the Release (or `InRelease` )file and that's why `apt` shows `unknown`.

For example, a typical standard Release file may have these entries (taken from Ubuntu's official repository's `InRelease` file)

```
Origin: Ubuntu
Label: Ubuntu
Suite: zesty
Version: 17.04
Codename: zesty
Date: Wed, 12 Apr 2017  2:53:23 UTC
Architectures: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
```

Check [this section](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format#A.22Release.22_files) of debian wiki for more information about Release file format.

And check [this slightly old but my favorite guide](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1090731) to create a proper Ubuntu local repository.

### `now`

`now` refers to the version of the package currently installed (and thus considered available). The info is maintained in `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file. I have these entries in `apt list --installed`

```
zlib1g/zesty,now 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
zlib1g-dev/ubuntu-local,zesty,now 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
zsync/zesty,now 0.6.2-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
```

As you can see `zsync` has a `now` entry which means it's installed and available as such. If you see no other entries except `now` it would mean you have a package installed which isn't available to reinstall from any known repository.

Here is the output of `apt policy zsync` again from the same system.

```
zsync:
  Installed: 0.6.2-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.6.2-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 0.6.2-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.6.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 file:/mnt/Data/Software/Linux/Debian_Packages/xenial_debs2  Packages
```

As you can see `/var/lib/dpkg/status` was listed as a repo for `zsync` which means it's currently installed.

Comment: @Arun you're welcome. I still insist to update the question with a textual output. Image is hard for us to work with